# How to send parameters to a reference method in a stream (java 8)?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, jodatime

I have a list of activities(Activity) and I want to determine a data structure of the form `Map(String, DateTime)` (not Duration or Period; `DateTime` it's a must) that maps. For each activity the total duration computed over the monitoring period.

The class Activity has: `activityLabel(String)`, `startTime(DateTime)`, `endTime(DateTime)`. I use `joda` time.
This is what I have done:

```
Map<String, DateTime> durations = activities.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                  it -> it.activityLabel,
                                  it ->new DateTime(0,0,0,0,0,0)
                                 //,DateTime::plus
                                 ));
```

I guess I should use [DateTime plus(ReadablePeriod period)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod)) or  [DateTime    plus(ReadableDuration duration)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadableDuration)) , but I don't know how to send a parameter of type Duration or Period to the method reference.

How can I achieve this result?

EDIT: For the input:

2011-12-03 01:00:00 2011-12-03 9:00:00  Sleeping

2011-12-04 03:00:00 2011-12-04 10:30:00 Sleeping

I should have the output: Sleeping 0-0-0 15:30:00 (years,months,days,hours,minutes,seconds)

Comment: why plus? shouldn't you be doing `endTime - startTime`?

Comment: I don't really understand how you're supposed to represent a duration using a DateTime. The 21 of May 2017 in New York time zone is not a duration at all.

Comment: I mean plus(endTime-startTime)

Comment: I think you're right. I guess I received a bad specified task...

Comment: @ProgramerGirl1996 who/what need `??.plus(endTime-startTime)`? usually `endTime - startTime` is a `Duration` not a `DateTime`.

Comment: @JB Nizet But it is possible to represent a period using DateTime? I mean..it's not really logical, but is it possible?

Comment: Well, you could decide to always use the same time zone (UTC), and that a duration of 2 hours would be represented by the DateTime epoch + 2 hours UTC, but it's really not a good idea. Why not use the appropriate class: Duration?

Comment: @JB Nizet The time zone is not important in this task. I don't want to use Duration because the task was specified exactly like this: " determine a data structure of the form Map(String, DateTime)"... It's weird because the year(for example) in DateTime refers to a valid year(i think), not to a period of a year, and I have to find the total period a man is doing an activity

Answer (score 3):

The code (using a Period) would look like this:

```
 Map<String, Period> map = activities.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Activity::activityLabel, ac -> new Period(ac.getStartTime(), ac.getEndTime()),
                    (left, right) -> left.plus(right)));
```

If you really want to output that `Period` as a String, you need `PeriodFormatter`.

```
 private static PeriodFormatter periodFormatter() {
    return new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendYears().appendSeparator("-")
            .appendMonths().appendSeparator("-")
            .appendDays().appendLiteral(" ")
            .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
            .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
            .appendSeconds().toFormatter();
}
```

And then your code would look more like this:

```
 Map<String, String> map = activities.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            Activity::getLabel,
                            ac -> new Period(ac.getStartTime(), ac.getEndTime()),
                            Period::plus),
                    m -> m.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Entry::getKey,
                            e -> e.getValue().toString(periodFormatter)))));

    System.out.println(map);  // {Sleeping=00-00-00 15:30:00
```

Comment: First, up-vote, sir. Indeed, my first answer is more simular with yours. But the OP need a `DateTime` so I changed my answer to using `groupingBy`, and I found you can aslo using `groupingBy` to avoid creates streams twice and make the code more simpler than `toMap`  when diplays `Period`s in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned in comment that you really need is a `DateTime` not a `Period`.

Since the [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) has no api for `DateTime.plus(DateTime)`/`DateTime.minus(DateTime)`, but you can [plus](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod)) / [minus](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod)) a `Period` on a `DateTime` , then you need a `DateTime` to start, and the code using [Collectors api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) is replacing `toMap` with `groupingBy` which is more **efficiently** and **expressiveness** for doing the task in your case:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.now();

Map<String, DateTime> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    it -> it.activityLabel,
    Collectors.mapping(
        it -> new Period(it.startTime, it.endTime),
        // the important section is here:
        // 1. merge all of periods by using reducing
        // 2. convert a Period to a DateTime by collectingAndThen
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.reducing(Period.ZERO, Period::plus),
                start::plus
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: I understand your point. I asked again because I was trying to find a way of doing it using DateTime... I guess I will use Period because it's more appropriate

Comment: @ProgramerGirl1996 hi, you can convert a `Period` to a `DateTime`, but you need a `DateTime` to start, then you can [plus](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod)) a `Period` as: `start.plus(period)` that return a `DateTime`.

Comment: @holi-java This will only work because `DateTime` is thread-safe (at least it is documented as such). IF you add a parallel stream that is...

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your feedback, but `DateTime` is a value objects, it has no side effects. And I reducing `Period`s not `DateTime`s.

Comment: @holi-java that is irrelevant as far as I can see. You are updating a shared variable - unless actions from one thread are entirely visible by the other; you can not guarantee what that `DateTime` will contain when multiple threads are done updating it. Since this a thread-safe object, you are on the safe side. But *generally* this is bad approach.

Comment: @Eugene sir, I have never updated a shared variable at all. `DateTime#plus` returns a new `DateTime` instead. So it is thread-safe in multi-threads. Am I right?

Comment: @holi-java what I mean is this actually : `int i[] = { 0 };
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
                .parallel()
                .collect(Collectors.mapping(x -> {
                    ++i[0];
                    return x;
                }, Collectors.toList()));` When this is done there are no guarantees that `i[0] == 4`. Same happens in your case. *But* since `DateTime` is thread-safe you are ok. It's like using `AtomicInteger` instead of `i[]`

Comment: @Eugene thanks, yes, sir. I can't update a `DateTime` since it is an value object that is immutable and thread-safely.